# The potential impact of an if statement inside a loop

Tags: c#

Assuming we have the `Boolean check = false`, and the value for this variable is either always true or false meaning it never changes through the loop, would the following be more computationally efficient than the latter one?

First:

```
// The value of check variable never changes inside the loop.
if(check){
   for(int i=0; i < array.Length; i++){
       sb.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\"", array[i].ToString());
   }
}
else{
   for(int i=0; i < array.Length; i++){
       sb.Append(String.Format("{0}", array[i].ToString());
   }
}
```

Second:

```
for(int i=0; i < array.Length; i++){
   if(check){
      sb.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\"", array[i].ToString());
   }
   else{
      sb.Append(String.Format("{0}", array[i].ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. The compiler doesn't know if it's gonna change or not so it'll  run the check every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no general answer for that, especially on modern CPUs.

**In theory**

Theoretically, the less branches you have in your code, the better. So since the second statement repeats the branches once per loop iteration, you need more processing time and hence it is less efficient.

**In practice**

Modern CPUs do what is called *branch prediction*. That means they try to figure out in advance if a branch is taken. If the prediction is correct, the branch is free (free as in 0 CPU cycles), if it is incorrect, the CPU has to flush its execution queue and the branch is very expensive (as in *much* more than 1 CPU cycle).

In your specific examples you have two branch types, the ones for the loop and the ones for the `if`. Since your condition for the `if` does not change and the loop has a fixed number of executions, both branches are trivial to predict for the branch prediction engine and you can expect both alternatives to perform the same.

**In coding practice**

Performance considerations rarely have an impact in practice (especially in this case because of branch prediction), so you should choose the better coding style. And I would consider the second alternative to be better in this respect.

Comment: The better coding style would (typically) be to put the format string in an `if` statement. The `for` loop is repeated logic and violates the DRY principle. With the format string extracted, it's more readable, concise and performant.

Comment: @Abel: I'm comparing the tow suggested solutions. Best practice would be using constants, too.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Just wanted to add to your solution, which is an excellent explanation, btw)).

Answer (score 2):

Also, the whole code could be refactored as:

```
Func<int, string> getText;

if(array.Length > 2) getText = i => $@"A - ""{array[i]}""";
else getText = i => $@"B - ""{array[i]}""";

for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) sb.Append(getText(i));
```

That is, you define the whole `Func<int, string>` based on some boolean check, and later you do the whole `for` loop against the pre-defined `Func<int, string>` which won't need a check anymore, and also, you don't repeat yourself!

See how I've used interpolated strings, which is a syntactic sugar of regular string concatenation, and I've used verbatim strings to escape quots using *double quots*.

In summary:

- You avoid repeating yourself.
- You avoid many calls to `string.Format`.
- You avoid many calls to `string.ToString()`.
- You reduce code lines.
- Compiled code is simpler, because delegates end up in a call to a method in a generated internal class, and the rest of operations are just syntactic sugar over regular string concatenation...

### I know...

I know that my answer doesn't address the question at all, but I wanted to give the OP some hints on how to optimize the code from a high-level point of view, instead of focusing on low-level details.

Comment: @MickyD Well, I've just added a new update because I knew that someone was going to say "this doesn't answer the question" :D

Comment: Hehe.  Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @MickyD Same! ;) I know that it's not addressing the question, but I feel that sometimes StackOverflow is a good tool to provide alternatives to OPs' reasonings. If I'm mistaken, I'll drop my answer, but isn't **Take 2** avoiding `string.Format` calls, code repetition, and increasing readability? Simpler code and even more efficient, since most of I've used there is just syntactic sugar which ends up in very simple operations. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @MickyD Oops my answer is broken, first approach was using an `Action<i>`, I'm going to fix this. Thank you for your good comments!

Answer (score 2):

Sefe's answer is very interesting, but if you know in advance that the value will not change throughout the loop, then you really shouldn't be checking within the loop.

It is preferable to separate the decision from the loop entirely:

```
var template = check ? "\"{0}\"" : "{0};
for(int i=0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(String.Format(check, array[i].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First one is more efficient. But compiler optimizations potentially can fix the latter case during compilation.

Comment: In my opinion there should be either no difference or the difference should be very very negligible. But I wanna make sure.

Comment: @arrr, this cannot be fixed during compilation, unless `check` is a constant, but then the code would be redundant to begin with. Branch prediction *may* influence performance, as shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I said "potentially can fix". But compiler can for example move expression from while condition and assign it to variable like `while (!flag) { }` -> `if (!flag) while (true) { }` if `flag` is not changing, so I guess it may be can do same thing with variable inside a loop if it is only read.